# Pandas Find Position of a Keyword in a Row using another Series as the Lookup value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand how to apply `str.find()` in order to find the index position of a keyword within a string in a pandas series. I want to use another series containing a string in the same dataframe as the input value of for `str.find()`.

The output I'm trying to create is another series with a integer of the position of the keyword in the string. e.g for the first row I'd expect a `1` and for the second row I'd expect `2`.

The goal is to use the exact match of the keyword/key phrase in `query`to find the exact match within the string in 'Title' and return the position of the keyword within the string in `Title`. If the keyword/phrase doesn't exist then 0 would display.

**Expected output**

```
example_data = pd.DataFrame(([['key word1', 'key word1'], ['key word2', 'Find key word2, not key word1 or key word3 in title']]), columns=['query', 'Title'])
```

**My attempt**

```
example_data = pd.DataFrame(([['key word1', 'key word1'], ['key word2', 'Find key word2, not keyword1 or keyword3 in title']]), columns=['query', 'Title'])

example_data['query_position'] = example_data['Title'].str.find(example_data['query'])
```

The error I get is:

> TypeError: expected a string object, not Series

I'm not entirely sure how to iterate over the the series and feed the string value in the series into `str.find()`.

Anyone help would be great!

Comment: So is not possible use `split`? But then is how possible get order? I think if last value is `a  b c d key word4 keyword1 key word2` then `key word2` is 4th? Or 2?

Comment: It's not possible to use split on the `query` because it breaks the word up. I was thinking that may it need `regex` to take the query match it, then produce the index position. I can't figure out how to make that work though. The example below works well but splits the word in `query` so doesn't produce the right output.

Comment: Ya, I know, only missing logic for order if not possible split. Because then it means some whitespaces are used for split kyewords, another whitesapces contains keywords. ANd if want some general solution it is impossible distinguish between

Comment: Only theoretical way should be remove all whitespaces in keywords like `key word1` to `keyword1` in both columns and then possible split between... Is it possible?

Comment: The white space will also give the position if we strip it then we can't know the query's position in the title. Text processing is so tricky! :)

Comment: yop, only possible way is separate keywords ot create some dataset with all keywords, also with spaces...

Comment: what is expected output on your updated sample? are they still `1` and `2` ?

Comment: @AndyL.Yes still 1 and 2

Comment: On 2nd row, from this `'Find key word2, not key word1 or key word3 in title'`, searching the phrase `key word2` returns `2`. Could you explain more on how to come up with `2`?

Comment: @AndyL. I'm not sure if this is what you mean but 2 is the position of the phrase from `query` in the `Title` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is more pythonic but works.

`str.find` can't help because it returns index as number of characters, not words.

```
example_data['query_position'] = [len(t.split(q)[0].split(' ')) if len(t.split(q)) > 1 else 0 for t, q in zip(example_data['Title'].str.lower(), example_data['query'].str.lower())]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use [`series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` to convert to dataframe then using [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) check if dataframe matches the other series:

```
example_data['position'] = (example_data['Title'].str.split(expand=True)
                             .eq(example_data['query']).idxmax(1)+1)
print(example_data)
```

---

```
      query                       Title  position
0  keyword1  keyword1 keyword2 keyword3         1
1  keyword1  keyword2 keyword1 keyword3         2
```

If there can be missing matches, you can use:

```
m = example_data['Title'].str.split(expand=True)
c = m.eq(example_data['query'])
example_data['position'] = np.where(c.any(1),c.idxmax(1)+1,np.nan)
```

Comment: I've never come across `.eq` what does it do. Is there a work around to make the starting number 1 rather than 0?

Comment: @NickDuddy just add 1 in the end and it works, updated the answer

Comment: adding 1 worked, thanks. Though, I've just realised that my example is flawed. I will update it. As I'm looking find the position of a key phase from query in the Title, not the first word in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.index` but also check matching, if no match is returned `-1`:

```
out = [b.split().index(a) + 1 
       if a in b 
       else -1 
       for a, b in zip(example_data['query'], example_data['Title'])]
print (out)
[1, 2]

example_data['query_position'] = out
```

Comment: This gives me a bool. I want to the index position of the keyword e.g. 1. I should have said in my question what the expect output was. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to create a new column, `query_position`, that checks for whether a string in `query` appears in `Title`, and then gives the position. The `str.find()` method returns -1 if the queried string isn't present in the other string. You've said you want it to return 0 if the string isn't present, but that may cause confusion if the string you're searching for is present and is located at the 0 index.

If you really want to make it zero, here's how I would approach the problem using `str.find()`:

```
# Quick custom function
def match_string(Title, query):
    s = Title.find(query)
    if s == -1:
        return 0
    else:
        return s

# Use the .apply() function to create a new column using the custom function
example_data['query_position'] = example_data.apply(lambda x: match_string(x['Title'],
 x['query']), axis=1)
```

If you want to leave -1 as-is, then this is the way to apply the `str.find()` function to your dataframe:

```
example_data['query_position'] = example_data.apply(lambda x:str.find(x['Title'],
                                 x['query']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to have a column that just enumerates rows like this:

```
example_data['enum'] = range(example_data.count())
```

Then if you find the query string inside the title string, just update row_id like this:

```
example_data['query_position'] = example_data.apply(lambda x: x['enum'] if x['Title'].contains(x['query']) else 0)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. But, adding a row that will fail:

```
ample_data['query_position'] = pd.DataFrame(([['key word1', 'key word1'], ['key word2', 'Find key word2, not key word1 or key word3 in title'], ['kew word3', 'kew word1']]), columns=['query', 'Title'])
```

And then using a list comprehension to generate the new column:

```
ample_data['query_position'] = [title.find(query) if title.find(query) > -1 else 0 for title, query in zip(ample_data['Title'], ample_data['query'])]
```

which gives:

```
       query                                              Title  query_position
0  key word1                                          key word1               0
1  key word2  Find key word2, not key word1 or key word3 in ...               5
2  kew word3                                          kew word1               0
```

or leaving the default `-1` for not found:

```
ample_data['query_position'] = [title.find(query) for title, query in zip(ample_data['Title'], ample_data['query'])]
```

which gives:

```
       query                                              Title  query_position
0  key word1                                          key word1               0
1  key word2  Find key word2, not key word1 or key word3 in ...               5
2  kew word3                                          kew word1              -1
```